# How do I retrieve all rows which have a five digit number in one column

Tags: mysql, regex, numbers

my table looks something like this:

```
id | name      | notes
 1 | person 1  | bla bla bla bla
 2 | person 2  | bla 38728 bla bla
 3 | person 3  | bla83784 bla bla
 4 | person 4  | 73804
 5 | person 5  | bla bla 3388 bla bla
```

I would like a query that retrieves all rows which have five consecutive digits the column notes. The result shoud look this:

```
id | name      | notes
 2 | person 2  | bla 38728 bla bla
 3 | person 3  | bla83784 bla bla
 4 | person 4  | 73804
```

I thought this would be possible with REGEXP. But apparently I am doing something wrong

```
SELECT id, name, notes
  FROM table
 WHERE notes REGEXP '\d{5}'
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't understand `\d`, use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: What if there are 6 consecutive digits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following query. I'm using `*` because preceding and trailing characters could appear zero or more times.

```
SELECT id, name, notes FROM table WHERE Notes REGEXP '[0-9]{5}'
```

Comment: The `.*` on either end is unnecessary.